# Call SFML from excel

Tags: c++, excel, sfml, excel-addins

I have looked all over and perhaps it’s a strange thing to want to do but does anybody know if it’s possible to link an SFML graphic session to excel? I’d like to call and display an SFML graphic, from an excel button perhaps then have that SFML user interaction do some accessing and manipulation to the excel workbook. Any idea where to get started or if it’s possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you should probably limit the scope a bit. For example, should it be for a single file/workbook only or would you want to use an addin for that etc.? In the end you'd have to either write a dynamic link library (dll) with a C interface to be accessed or use CSFML for this.

Comment: I would love for this to be an add in if possible, but I don’t really know how to get a c++ addin to launch from a button. It should work for any excel workbook that calls it. Which one would you recommend for this? I wrote this whole thing as a JavaScript add in and pretty much completed it, but It Can have up to 1000 dom elements I need to loop through and manipulate so it gets too slow even though I believe I’ve optimized almost as much as I can .